# How to declare two event types in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to declare the event type as Event and MouseEvent in handelClickOutside().

```
 const ref = useRef<any>(null);

 useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
  };
 }, []);

 const handleClickOutside = (event: Event) => {
   if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
     const title         = "Cancel Confirmation";
      const message      = `Do you want to close?`;
      const onOk         = () => onClose(event);
      const cancelButton = "No, back to edit";
      const okButton     = "Yes, Cancel";
      openConfirmDialog(title, message, onOk, undefined, undefined, cancelButton, okButton);
   }
 };

 return(
     <div className="container" ref={ref}>
     //code
     </div>

 );
```

I need to declare that event types are Event and MouseEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create interfaces as shown below

```
interface CustomEvent extends Event, MouseEvent{

}
```

then you can use like this

```
 const handleClickOutside = (event: CustomEvent) => {
 -----
 -----
```